# @Query says it does not have the fields, although I have them in the query itself -> Kotlin Android Room

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I got this code in my DAO:

```
@Query("select Conversation.*, User.* from Conversation join User on Conversation.createdBy = User.userUuid where conversationUuid = :conversationUuid")
fun selectAllForOverview(conversationUuid: UUID): LiveData<List<ConversationSelectAllForOverview>>
```

This is `ConversationSelectAllForOverview`

```
data class ConversationSelectAllForOverview(
    @Embedded(prefix = "arg0")
    val arg0: DbConversation,
    @Embedded(prefix = "arg1")
    val arg1: DbUser
)
```

I read that I needed to annotate my fields with a `prefix` to get rid of errors when they have common field names. I get this error and I don't know how I can remove it. I am 100% sure all the columns are available, since `DbConversation` and `DbUser` are just generated from the database. How can I fix this problem? `DbConversation` and `DbUser` share some columns, see the definition of `DbConversation` here: https://gist.github.com/Jasperav/381243e7b3cf387bfc0e9f1343f9faeb. `DbUser` looks the same.

```
error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields
 [conversationUuid,createdBy,tsCreated,distanceMapped,showOnMap,showOnOverview,allowMessagesByInRangeRegularUsers,allowMessagesByOutOfRangeRegularUsers,stillReadableForOutOfRangeRegularUsers,freedomInReplies,title,subject,likes,latitude,longitude,hasPassword,isSubscribed,showOnMapScreen,isLiked,bypassChecks,isHidden,nsfw,currentDirectEvents,totalDirectEventsAfterLastJoin,subscriptions,userUuid,username,karma,tsCreated,allowsPrivateChats,allowsNsfw,thisUserBlockedCurrentUser,incomingFriendshipRequest,outstandingFriendshipRequest,friends,bio,appRoleMapped]
 in entity.ConversationSelectAllForOverview even though they are
 annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query:
 [conversationUuid,createdBy,tsCreated,distanceMapped,showOnMap,showOnOverview,allowMessagesByInRangeRegularUsers,allowMessagesByOutOfRangeRegularUsers,stillReadableForOutOfRangeRegularUsers,freedomInReplies,title,subject,likes,avatar,latitude,longitude,hasPassword,isSubscribed,showOnMapScreen,isLiked,bypassChecks,isHidden,conversationReportReasonMapped,nsfw,currentDirectEvents,totalDirectEventsAfterLastJoin,lastReadConversationEventPk,mostRecentConversationEventUuid,relevance,subscriptions,userUuid,username,karma,tsCreated,allowsPrivateChats,allowsNsfw,avatar,currentUserBlockedThisUserTsCreated,thisUserBlockedCurrentUser,searchScreenScore,recentSearchedTsCreated,userReportReasonMapped,incomingFriendshipRequest,outstandingFriendshipRequest,friends,bio,appRoleMapped]
     public abstract androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<entity.ConversationSelectAllForOverview>>
 selectAllForOverview(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Issue**

You are **prefixing** the columns in the **`@Embedded`** annotation in conjunction with the output columns not being prefixed according to the query.

For example the **ConversationSelectAllForOverview** class is expecting to find the column named **arg0conversationUuid** in the output/result of the query but the query only has the column **conversationUuid**.

**The Fix**

Instead of using `select Conversation.*, User.* ....` you need to use

```
 select Conversation.conversationUuid AS arg0conversationUuid, Conversation.createdBy AS arg0createdBy ....
```

- **`AS`** giving the output *conversationUuid* column an ***alias*** of *arg0conversationUuid* etc.

i.e. **for every column in both tables you have to alias the actual column with it's prefix.**

e.g. using (only partially adjusted):-

```
@Query("select " +
        "Conversation.conversationUuid AS arg0conversationUuid" +
        ", Conversation.createdBy AS arg0createdBy" +
        ", Conversation.tsCreated AS arg0tsCreated" +
        ", Conversation.distanceMapped AS arg0distanceMapped" +
        /* .... */
        ", User.* from Conversation join User on Conversation.createdBy = User.userUuid where conversationUuid = :conversationUuid")
fun selectAllForOverview(conversationUuid: UUID): LiveData<List<ConversationSelectAllForOverview>>
```

- the message is then `The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [showOnMap,showOnOverview ....`

  - i.e. conversationUuid, createdBy, tsCreated and distanceMapped are now not included in the field-column mismatch list.

**Alternative Fix** (untested and reliant upon Room 2.5.0 libraries )

Another solution, which may work with Room 2.5.0 (untested) would be to use the `@Relation` annotation instead of the `@Embedded` annotation for the child(ren). e.g. without any other changes other than:-

```
data class ConversationSelectAllForOverview(
    @Embedded/*(prefix = "arg0")*/
    val arg0: DbConversation,
    @Relation(
        entity = DbUser::class,
        parentColumn = "createdBy",
        entityColumn = "userUuid"
    )
    val arg1: DbUser
)
```

and then using :-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM Conversation WHERE conversationUUid=:conversationUuid")
fun selectAllForOverview(conversationUuid: UUID): LiveData<List<ConversationSelectAllForOverview>>
```

Then it compiles successfully (again not run, see below). i.e. there are no issues with the duplicated columns (again see below).

You could also use (note the function name being different to allow both to be compiled):-

```
@Transaction
@Query("select Conversation.*,User.* from Conversation join User on Conversation.createdBy = User.userUuid where conversationUuid = :conversationUuid")
fun selectAllForOverviewAlt(conversationUuid: UUID): LiveData<List<ConversationSelectAllForOverview>>
```

- **However** the **JOIN**ed columns are superfluous as Room uses the `@Relationship` parameters to then build the DbUser object via a subsequent query (hence the @Transaction).

***NOTE** Room used to take the last value found, for a like named output column, and apply that last value to all of the fields so named. This has reportedly been fixed with 2.5.0. This hasn't been confirmed as being the case though. As such you may get unintended results, so if you take this approach you should confirm that values are as expected (i.e. check the values of the like named columns/fields).*

**Additional a Demo**

The following is a working demo based upon the code as per the question DbConversation class. BUT, to simplify matters other code has been made up and additionally many of the fields have been commented out. LiveData has been commented out and `.allowMainThreadQueries` to simplify the demo.

The Demo uses both fixes and for the `@Relation` both the original query and the suggested more consice query.

A debugging breakpoint has been used to demonstrate the sets of 3 returns.

**The Database Code** (everything needed for the demo plus some that isn't due to commenting out). It should be Noted that much of the code may differ, simple assumptions have been made.

:-

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "Conversation",
    primaryKeys = ["conversationUuid"],
    indices = [/*Index(value = ["nsfw", "relevance"]), Index(value = ["isSubscribed"]),*/ Index(value = ["createdBy"])/*, Index(
        value = ["avatar"]
    ), Index(value = ["mostRecentConversationEventUuid"])*/],
    foreignKeys = [/*ForeignKey(
        entity = DbConversationEventMostRecent::class,
        childColumns = ["mostRecentConversationEventUuid"],
        parentColumns = ["conversationEventUuid"],
        onDelete = SET_NULL,
        onUpdate = CASCADE,
    ), ForeignKey(
        entity = DbMedia::class,
        childColumns = ["avatar"],
        parentColumns = ["mediaUuid"],
        onDelete = CASCADE,
        onUpdate = NO_ACTION,
    ), */ForeignKey(
        entity = DbUser::class,
        childColumns = ["createdBy"],
        parentColumns = ["userUuid"],
        onDelete = CASCADE,
        onUpdate = NO_ACTION,
    )]
)
data class DbConversation(
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
    val conversationUuid: UUID,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
    val createdBy: UUID,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val tsCreated: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
    val distanceMapped: ConversationDistance,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val showOnMap: Boolean,
    /*
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val showOnOverview: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val allowMessagesByInRangeRegularUsers: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val allowMessagesByOutOfRangeRegularUsers: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val stillReadableForOutOfRangeRegularUsers: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val freedomInReplies: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
    val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
    val subject: String,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val likes: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
    val avatar: UUID?,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.REAL)
    val latitude: Double,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.REAL)
    val longitude: Double,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val hasPassword: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val isSubscribed: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val showOnMapScreen: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val isLiked: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val bypassChecks: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val isHidden: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
    val conversationReportReasonMapped: ConversationReportReason?,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val nsfw: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val currentDirectEvents: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val totalDirectEventsAfterLastJoin: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
    val lastReadConversationEventPk: ConversationEventPk?,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)


    val mostRecentConversationEventUuid: UUID?,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.REAL)
    val relevance: Double?,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    val subscriptions: Long
    */

)

@Dao
interface AllDAOs {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(dbUser: DbUser): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(dbConversation: DbConversation): Long

    @Query("select " +
            "Conversation.conversationUuid AS arg0conversationUuid" +
            ", Conversation.createdBy AS arg0createdBy" +
            ", Conversation.tsCreated AS arg0tsCreated" +
            ", Conversation.distanceMapped AS arg0distanceMapped" +
            ", Conversation.showOnMap AS arg0showOnMap" +
            /* .... */
            ",User.userUuid AS arg1userUuid" + /*?????? made up/incomplete/asssumed */
            ",User.userName AS arg1userName" +
            " from Conversation join User on Conversation.createdBy = User.userUuid where conversationUuid = :conversationUuid")
    fun selectAllForOverviewOld(conversationUuid: UUID): /*LiveData<*/List<OldConversationSelectAllForOverview>/*>*/

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Conversation WHERE conversationUuid=:conversationUuid")
    fun selectConversationByUuid(conversationUuid: UUID): List<DbConversation>


    @Query("SELECT * FROM Conversation WHERE conversationUuid=:conversationUuid")
    fun selectAllForOverview(conversationUuid: UUID): /*LiveData<*/List<ConversationSelectAllForOverview>/*>*/

    @Query("select Conversation.*,User.* from Conversation join User on Conversation.createdBy = User.userUuid where conversationUuid = :conversationUuid")
    fun selectAllForOverviewAlt(conversationUuid: UUID): /*LiveData<*/List<ConversationSelectAllForOverview>/*>*/
}

data class ConversationDistance(
    val blah: String
)
data class ConversationReportReason(
    val blah: String
)
data class ConversationEventPk(
    val blah: ByteArray
)

class RoomTypeConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromConversationDistanceToJSON(conversationDistance: ConversationDistance): String = Gson().toJson(conversationDistance)
    @TypeConverter
    fun toConversationDistanceFromJSON(json: String): ConversationDistance = Gson().fromJson(json,ConversationDistance::class.java)
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromConversationReportReasonToJSON(conversationReportReason: ConversationReportReason): String = Gson().toJson(conversationReportReason)
    @TypeConverter
    fun toConversationReportReasonFromJSON(json: String): ConversationReportReason = Gson().fromJson(json,ConversationReportReason::class.java)
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromConversationEventPkToByteArray(conversationEventPk: ConversationEventPk): ByteArray = ByteArray(100)
    @TypeConverter
    fun toConversationEventPkFromByteArray(byteArray: ByteArray): ConversationEventPk = ConversationEventPk(byteArray)

}

@Entity(tableName = "User")
data class DbUser(
    @PrimaryKey
    val userUuid: UUID,
    val userName: String
)
@Entity
data class DbMedia(
    @PrimaryKey
    val mediaUuid: UUID,
    val mediaName: String
)
@Entity
data class DbConversationEventMostRecent(
    @PrimaryKey
    val conversationEventUuid: UUID
)

data class ConversationSelectAllForOverview(
    @Embedded/*(prefix = "arg0")*/
    val arg0: DbConversation,
    @Relation(
        entity = DbUser::class,
        parentColumn = "createdBy",
        entityColumn = "userUuid"
    )
    val arg1: DbUser
)

data class OldConversationSelectAllForOverview(
    @Embedded(prefix = "arg0")
    val arg0: DbConversation,
    @Embedded(prefix = "arg1")
    val arg1: DbUser
)

@TypeConverters(value = [RoomTypeConverters::class])
@Database(entities = [DbMedia::class,DbUser::class,DbConversationEventMostRecent::class,DbConversation::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs
    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* For brevity of demo */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

The Activity Code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        val u1uuid = UUID(10L,10L)
        val u2uuid = UUID(11L,12L)
        val c1uuid = UUID(20L,20L)
        val c2uuid = UUID(21L,21L)
        val c3uuid = UUID(22L,10L)
        val c4uuid = UUID(15L,10L)

        dao.insert(DbUser(u1uuid,"Fred"))
        dao.insert(DbUser(u2uuid,"Mary"))
        dao.insert(DbConversation(c1uuid,u1uuid,0, ConversationDistance("blah blah blah"),true))
        dao.insert(DbConversation(c2uuid,u2uuid,0,ConversationDistance("uhm uhm uhm"),true))
        dao.insert(DbConversation(c3uuid,u1uuid,0,ConversationDistance("meh meh meh"),true))
        dao.insert(DbConversation(c4uuid,u1uuid,0,ConversationDistance("good good good"),true))

        val c1 = dao.selectConversationByUuid(c1uuid)
        val c2 = dao.selectConversationByUuid(c2uuid)
        val c3 = dao.selectConversationByUuid(c3uuid)
        val c4 = dao.selectConversationByUuid(c4uuid)

        val t1c1 = dao.selectAllForOverviewOld(c1uuid)
        val t1c2 = dao.selectAllForOverview(c1uuid)
        val t1c3 = dao.selectAllForOverviewAlt(c1uuid)

        val t2c1 = dao.selectAllForOverviewOld(c2uuid)
        val t2c2 = dao.selectAllForOverview(c2uuid)
        val t2c3 = dao.selectAllForOverviewAlt(c2uuid)

        if (t1c1==null) t1c1==null /*<<<<<<<<<< BREAKPOINT HERE >>>>>>>>>>*/
    }
}
```

When run from a fresh install, then The debug window, with t1?? and t2?? expanded:-

[image]

As can be seen all 3 queries produce the same result. **As such the simplest solution would be to**

- ensure that you are using Room 2.5.0 libraries, AND
- use `@Relation` instead of `@Embedded` and use the more concise query just extracting the relevant DbConversation(s).

Comment: Room is really horrible that it forces me to do this. Why doesn't it deserialize the columns by index, rather by name? Anyway, I fixed this problem by prefixing the columns as suggested... it works but yeah, it's ugly :(

Comment: @J.Doe if you were to just use pure Objects (aka `@Relation`) then there is no need to a) code the JOIN or b) to use prefixes. Personally I would always use unique column names, probably with the tablename as part of the name. Not saying you should, just saying that you could.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at your classes DbConversation and DbUser and make sure these classes are `@Embeddable`. If not, put the annotation on the class.
Another solution is look at the error again. It say that query return a bunch of columns that your DTO (ConversationSelectAllForOverview) doens't hold; the fields of your DTO are the objects and not the columns fields. You can create an interface receiving all those columns that db return:

```
interface nameInterface(
    val conversationUuid: Any,
    val createdBy: Any,
    val tsCreated: Any,
    val distanceMapped: Any,
    val showOnMap: Any,
    val showOnOverview: Any,
    val allowMessagesByInRangeRegularUsers: Any,
    val allowMessagesByOutOfRangeRegularUsers: Any,
    val stillReadableForOutOfRangeRegularUsers: Any,
    val freedomInReplies: Any,
    val title: Any,
    val subject: Any,
    val likes: Any,
    val latitude: Any,
    val longitude: Any,
    val hasPassword: Any,
    val isSubscribed: Any,
    val showOnMapScreen: Any,
    val isLiked: Any,
    val bypassChecks: Any,
    val isHidden: Any,
    val nsfw: Any,
    val currentDirectEvents: Any,
    val totalDirectEventsAfterLastJoin: Any,
    val subscriptions: Any,
    val userUuid: Any,
    val username: Any,
    val karma: Any,
    val tsCreated: Any,
    val allowsPrivateChats: Any,
    val allowsNsfw: Any,
    val thisUserBlockedCurrentUser: Any,
    val incomingFriendshipRequest: Any,
    val outstandingFriendshipRequest: Any,
    val friends: Any,
    val bio: Any,
    val appRoleMapped: Any)
```

Comment: `Embeddable` does not exist